# R character to datetime resulting in NA

Tags: r, posixct

Yes, I have found a lot of methods

But for me, there is no way to do it.

I have a csv file, I read it into R

```
Week <- read.csv(file="week.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried to convert StartTime and EndTime to datetime(For example:2019-01-04 15:13:07)

I tried these methods

```
Week <- read.csv(file="week.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)%>%
              mutate(StartTime = as.POSIXct(StartTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

and

```
Week$StartTime <- setDT(Week)[,ymd_hms(Week$StartTime)]
```

and

```
Week$StartTime <- as.POSIXct(Week$StartTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But both return NA

I don't know what else can be done.

Attach a file and hope someone can help me.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qIOWkoVwlMu-Y6GZ_Nu0WqlcFRzyTO2v

Thank you

Supplementary text:

```
library(data.table)
Week=data.table(First=c("sat","sun","sat","sun","sat","sun","sat","sun","holiday"),
                StartTime=c("2018-09-01 00:00:00","2018-09-02 00:00:00","2018-09-08 00:00:00","2018-09-09 00:00:00","2018-09-15 00:00:00","2018-09-16 00:00:00","2018-09-22 00:00:00","2018-09-23 00:00:00","2018-09-24 00:00:00"),
                EndTime=c("2018-09-01 23:59:59","2018-09-02 23:59:59","2018-09-08 23:59:59","2018-09-09 23:59:59","2018-09-15 23:59:59","2018-09-16 23:59:59","2018-09-22 23:59:59","2018-09-23 23:59:59","2018-09-24 23:59:59"))
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Generally users don't like clicking on unknown links to files; can you copy a few lines from the csv and include as text?

Comment: Hi, I will change the link to GOOGLE DRIVE 以及 text

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate the issue. Each of these methods seems to work just fine, and I get the expected datetimes and no NAs, which means the issue probably has nothing to do with the data. It might be an issue with your environment or with how R has been set up.

Comment: Thank you, I try to see it with other computers.